# Saving intent data in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating a simple survey app in android studio. I have multiple intents, and I start each one when the "next" buttons are pressed. I also have a back button that brings the user to the previous intent if they want to change an answer to a question. When I go forward again, none of the answers are saved. How can I get all the users answers to be maintained?

Comment: Save the data stored in the fields in `onPause` callback method.

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Answer (score 3):

There are two methods you can override in your activities:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState);
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState);
```

As you see you have access to the Bundle "savedInstanceState". If a user terminates an activity *onSaveInstanceState()* gets called and you have the possibility to save data which you want to restore later.

The method *onRestoreInstanceState()* only gets called if you have saved information in *onSaveInstanceState()* and offers you the chance to restore that data. It provides a bundle which contains the same data that you saved into the data during *onSaveInstanceState()*.

A bundle is basically a key-value list. To store a string for example you simply would call the *putString()*-Method of the bundle:

```
savedInstanceState.putString("myKey", "Hello World");
```

There are many data-types that you can store in a bundle (in general, every class that implements the interface *Parcelable* can be stored in a bundle).

More information:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

Comment: I want the survey answers to be physically saved, so when the user checks checkboxes or enters in editText they don't have to redo the survey. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a singleton class for your data and store the intends there in a List or Array. You can extend the Application class for this or just make your own singleton class.

Comment: When application gets killed while in the background those data will be lost

Comment: Sorry to say but there are better options provided by Android itself.

Comment: y well i didnt say its the best, also saving data to database while switching activities is kinda basic... so i thought that part was clear

Answer (score 0):

When your Activities are recreated they receive the callback [onCreate(Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)). Whatever you have saved in [onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) will appear in Bundle.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement a singleton class ,and use it in your application which extends **Application**.
Store your data to the singleton by map and provide getter and setter methods

Comment: A singleton class might be a bad approach, because it's a global state than could be hard to test. Another point is that your singleton isn't available if android kills the app because it is in the background for a longer time.